# VirtueMart Search Frustrations

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart, joomla-extensions

I am trying to implement a simple "Virtuemart Only" search in one of the custom modules on a site.
What I'd like is to be able to insert the search tags into an existing table in a **mod_custom** module. The problem is, I have no idea how to code an `<INPUT>` tag to work with VM.

Every Google search I've done returns solutions centered on either (1) installing the VM Advanced Search module, (2) using the basic VM Search module, or (3) using Modules Anywhere to load one of the previously mentioned modules into an existing space. Problem is, the site I'm working on doesn't need another module taking up space. It really just needs a simple `<INPUT>` field in a particular location that sends queries to VM.

Edit: To clarify my purpose, here is a partial of the source code I want to insert the search into:

```
<table id="product-search" class="product-search">
 <tbody>    
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><span class="search-title">Order Online</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="shopping-cart.png" /></td>
   <td><**SEARCH CODE HERE**></td>
  </tr>    
etc... etc...
```

So you can see, it's just a simple table with some icons, phone numbers, etc., with the search `<input>` (hopefully) inserted in the middle of it.

I'm guessing I just need to add some stupidly simple code like:

```
<form action="administrator/components/com_virtuemart/html/shop.search.php" method="get">
Product Search: <input type="text" name="fname" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Of course, I just get an error trying to directly access that particular script, so I'm wondering: Any VM gurus know how to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by scouring the page source for sites I know using VM (should have thought of that in the first place). The code is:

```
<div class="virtuemart_advsearch">
    <form name="adv_search" method="post" action="http://www.mywebsite.com">
        <input type="hidden" value="shop.browse" name="page"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="com_virtuemart" name="option"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="9999" name="Itemid"/>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="keyword1" class="inputbox"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" class="button search"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `<div>` isn't really necessary, but it keeps things neatly divided for now. This is not the cleanest implementation, but it'll do for now.

Comment: Ok, that works. One minor change I would make - change the Itemid value to the itemid of the default VM menu item on your site. That will help carry over the menu assignments for VM to your search page.

Comment: So, if I select my default VM products menu and the itemID is 48, I should recode to `<input type="hidden" value="48" name="Itemid"/>`?

Comment: Exactly. That should get VM to use the itemid for the results page.

Comment: Cool. I wouldn't have guessed that one on my own :-)

Comment: One small caveat because VM does some weird stuff to establish itemID. If it doesn't work, I wouldn't spend much time on it as it would require a VM core hack to make it work.

Comment: I'll avoid that at all costs :-) It's working great now, so I think I'll leave well enough alone. Thanks for you insights!

Comment: I know what you mean, don't want to mess up a VM that's working! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to just insert a tag in to a mod_custom module, that's not how it works. Did you try the VM Advanced Search Module?

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-products-search/8396

This takes the VM Adv search and puts it in a module. It should do what you need.

Comment: I did look at the module you mentioned, but it really wasn't what I was looking for. I did some hard source code searches on existing VM sites and cobbled together my own code, which is below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search product only in your site then it will be better if you use default product search module in virtue mart. It will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I could easily use the default module, but if you read my question carefully, you'll notice that I mentioned needing to insert the search into a custom module.

Comment: your comment will be easier to read if you edit it and remove the spacing before your paragraph, which is turning the whole thing into a <code> span via markup.